# Python Module Subfolder Structure

Tags: python

My end goal with my current Python project structure is to be able to do:

```
from module.file1 import class1
from module.file1.subfile1 import subclass1
```

I tried the following:

```
/module
    __init__.py
    file1.py: Class 1
    /file1
        __init__.py
        subfile1.py: Subclass 1
        subfile2.py: Subclass 2
    file2.py: Class 2
```

However, while the second import statement above works, the first one does not (tested via pip installing the root working directory). I've seen structures like this before in other libraries, so I believe it is possible. If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

This code says that `module` and `file1` are packages, and not modules:

```
from module.file1 import class1
from module.file1.subfile1 import subclass1
```

It is not correct to have both package (direcotry) `file1` and module (file) `file1`. There should be only a package.

For the class `class1` to be importable from `file1`, if should be placed in the `__init__.py` of the package.

Therefore, the structure should be modified this way:

```
/module
    __init__.py
    /file1
        __init__.py: Class 1
        subfile1.py: Subclass 1
        subfile2.py: Subclass 2
    file2.py: Class 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!